# game using JFrame and content should changes dynamically

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I want to build a game. Where I am using `JFrame` and I want to add images at different specific locations. and change them dynamically ...  Can anyone please suggest any links or give sample code ..

Comment: Which part are you stuck on?  Unless you ask a more specific question, this questions is 'overly broad'.

Comment: Sure, here's a link.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/  Go through every section.  Do not skip anything.  Go through a section 2, 3, or 6,000 times until you understand it.

Comment: See my article [Game Development Loop, Logic and Collision detection Java Swing 2D](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/code/444547/game-development-loop-logic-and-collision-detection-java-swing-2d). It includes the bare bones for a 2d game in java swing

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't pasted your code. I am assuming this link might help.

[how to change the contents of a JFrame after it has been displayed (java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761476/how-to-change-the-contents-of-a-jframe-after-it-has-been-displayed-java)